# Playing video from http server in android

Tags: android, video, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a list-view in which i am loading all video's from server's particular folder. now what i am trying to do is by clicking a list item it should play that video in video view. Everything seems to work perfect, but only problem i am facing is when i click on list-view item it is not playing that video.

PS. I am getting following log in error log, but my application is not stopping unfortunately, my display is keep showing me that video is loading in progress bar which i set in Asynctask, but when i checked in log cat i saw this error.

Of course i have searched in google as well as SO but i did not got satisfactory result.

Folowwing is my log cat message.

```
02-21 11:08:52.964: W/SurfaceFlinger(101):     nothing to do with mask 0x00000000
02-21 11:08:52.974: W/System.err(1992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-21 11:08:52.976: W/System.err(1992):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-21 11:08:52.976: W/System.err(1992):     at android.widget.MediaController$3.<init>(MediaController.java:474)
02-21 11:08:52.977: W/System.err(1992):     at android.widget.MediaController.<init>(MediaController.java:474)
02-21 11:08:52.978: W/System.err(1992):     at android.widget.MediaController.<init>(MediaController.java:210)
02-21 11:08:52.978: W/System.err(1992):     at iqual.fidol_final.ServerFileList.playVideo(ServerFileList.java:225)
02-21 11:08:52.979: W/System.err(1992):     at iqual.fidol_final.ServerFileList.access$3(ServerFileList.java:221)
02-21 11:08:52.979: W/System.err(1992):     at iqual.fidol_final.ServerFileList$PlayVideo$1.run(ServerFileList.java:181)
02-21 11:08:52.979: W/System.err(1992):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And following is my code.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                    String url1 = null;
                    Object o1 = myList.get(position);
                    url1 = o1.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim();
                    playVideo = (PlayVideo) new PlayVideo(url1).execute();
            }
        });
```

and this is my Asynctask to playvideo

```
class PlayVideo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        String baseURL;

        public PlayVideo(String baseURL) {
            this.baseURL = baseURL;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ServerFileList.this,
                    "    Buffering...", "please wait..", false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        playVideo(baseURL);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

and following is my playVideo method.

```
private void playVideo(String baseURL) {
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(baseURL);
        MediaController mc;

        mc = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(myUri);
        System.out.println("====Myuri=====" + myUri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
    }
```

I also tried to creating new thread in doInbackground method and by removing thread also, but this tricks does not worked for me.

also one thing that it showing error on line 225 that is `mc = new MediaController(this);`

Comment: you are trying to play video in a background thread. The ui elements will only be accessible via main thread. Basically you are calling playVideo from the background thread and in play video you are trying to find UI elements

Comment: please visit http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Working-with-MediaController,--VideoView-in-Android hope will help you

Comment: Why you are writing a separate thread inside the doInBackground() mehod ?

Comment: @InnocentKiller why you using AsyncTask ?? you can't play video without asynctask??

Comment: @Kedarnath, if i am not creating thread then it is giving me error.

Comment: @CapDroid, then what else i can do, if i am going to play directly then also i am not able to play.

Comment: @InnocentKiller it will take some time to load video from server

Comment: @InnocentKiller but you are actually creating a thread inside a thread. Do you know that ? What error it gives when you are not creating a Thread ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, it is giving error `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
`

Comment: @InnocentKiller I think I can solve this. I will get back you to on this.

Comment: @InnocentKiller can you upload the activity's code in which mListView is used. Also give me any single url that you are trying.

Comment: @InnocentKiller Ok, I am trying your code now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48021/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-innocentkiller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your AsyncTask and play your video directly using below code,

```
String url1 = null; 
Object o1 = myList.get(position); 
url1 = o1.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim(); 
playVideo(url1);
```

Answer (score 1):

U can Play Video in VideoView Try this Using Asynctask

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.playvideo);

VideoView v=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute("Video Url");
}

public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Uri, Void> {

Integer track = 0;

ProgressDialog dialog;


protected void onPreExecute() {

dialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayVideo.this);

dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait...");

dialog.setCancelable(true);

dialog.show();

 }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(final Uri... uri) {

        try {

            media = new MediaController(PlayVideo.this);

 v.setMediaController(media);

 media.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override

 public void onClick(View v) {

// next button clicked


  }

  }, new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    finish();
                }
            });

     media.show(10000);


   v.setVideoURI(uri[0]);

   v.requestFocus();

    v.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    v.start();

    dialog.dismiss();

    }

   });

        } 

  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();

  } 

  catch (IllegalStateException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();

   } 
     catch (SecurityException e) {

      // TODO Auto-generated catch block

      e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }

    @Override

  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

   try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(params[0]);

            publishProgress(uri);

   } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }
```